# How to use OpenID+OAuth in my website?

Tags: php, oauth, openid

I want to log in my website by using google account, now i can use google account to log in(by OpenID), but i don't know how to get user account and information in google?
Just like below link(which is provided by google)

http://googlecodesamples.com/hybrid/

This link can log in by user's google account, and list all the documents in user's google doc, so i guess by using OAuth can let me get user's account(such as example@gmail.com) and get relative information, but i don't know how to do?

PS. I use php to write my website

Comment: Have you clicked the link on that page that says `documentation`?

Answer (score 0):

I can't code the whole thing for you, but I'll try and give you a general outline of how it's done.

Sample Request URL:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
&openid.ns.pape=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/pape/1.0
&openid.ns.max_auth_age=300
&openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select
&openid.return_to=http://www.example.com/checkauth
&openid.realm=http://www.example.com/
&openid.assoc_handle=ABSmpf6DNMw
&openid.mode=checkid_setup
&openid.ui.ns=http://specs.openid.net/extensions/ui/1.0
&openid.ui.mode=popup
&openid.ui.icon=true
&openid.ns.ax=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0
&openid.ax.mode=fetch_request
&openid.ax.type.email=http://axschema.org/contact/email
&openid.ax.type.language=http://axschema.org/pref/language
&openid.ax.required=email,language
```

Then, you should receive this response URL as a redirect that you need to intercept:

```
http://www.example.com/checkauth
?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0 
&openid.mode=id_res
&openid.op_endpoint=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud
&openid.response_nonce=2008-09-18T04:14:41Zt6shNlcz-MBdaw
&openid.return_to=http://www.example.com:8080/checkauth
&openid.assoc_handle=ABSmpf6DNMw
&openid.signed=op_endpoint,claimed_id,identity,return_to,response_nonce,assoc_handle
&openid.sig=s/gfiWSVLBQcmkjvsKvbIShczH2NOisjzBLZOsfizkI=     &openid.identity=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id/id=ACyQatixLeLODscWvwqsCXWQ2sa3RRaBhaKTkcsvUElI6tNHIQ1_egX_wt1x3fAY983DpW4UQV_U
&openid.claimed_id=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id/id=ACyQatixLeLODscWvwqsCXWQ2sa3RRaBhaKTkcsvUElI6tNHIQ1_egX_wt1x3fAY983DpW4UQV_U
```

Once you get that URL, you all set! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use already existing authentication solution, rather than reinvent wheel:-)
Since you are not specifying what server scripting language you are using, e.g. for PHP take a look at:

http://opauth.org/

It's pretty easy implementation and supports not only google account but many others. 
It also pulls out some of account information you are interested in.

... or google for something like "openID  authentication framework" or "oauth framework":-)